# How to upload multi External Data file to Wave analytic salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I already know how to upload a .csv file to Wave analytic. But I can't do this with multi file (2 file).

I always got this error

```
(column: Column01) strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "\ufeff0464589401": invalid syntax
```

The first line of the second file :

```
0464589401
```

I have no idea

Comment: can you be more specific interms of data, are you web scraping?

Comment: @RichardSlater I already resolved this problem, but thank you for reply.

Comment: Could you post your solution?